# ¿Como puedo ejecutar el POSTBACK de un botón ASP en una ventana modal BLOCKUI?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Saludos, verán: diseñe una ventana modal con Jquery BlockUI. Dentro de mi ventana modal, hay un pequeño formulario y tengo un ASP:BUTTON (En este caso BtnAutorizar) con su respectivo evento CLICK en el CODE BEHIND. Sin embargo al llamar la ventana modal y hacer clic en el botón, este no hace no nada.

No estoy utilizando AJAX, pues requiero que se haga directamente el POSTBACK para refrescar la pagina después del proceso, estoy haciendo uso de MASTER PAGE.

Del lado del cliente tengo lo siguiente:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Solucion/layout/AdminMstr.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AlmacenFrm.aspx.cs" Inherits="Oranxe.Solucion.admin.AlmacenFrm" %>
```

```
  <div class="content">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

                <div class="page-title">
                    <h3>Almacén</h3>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-truck"></i> Demanda al proveedor</a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Demanda de sucursal</a>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-box">

                    <div role="form">

                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 19px;">
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LnkDescargarInventario" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-lg" OnClick="LnkDescargarInventario_Click" runat="server">Descargar inventario</asp:LinkButton>
                                    <a href="#" id="LnkSolictarAutorizacion" class="btn btn-border-theme btn-lg">Guardar ajustes</a>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Busqueda rapida:</label>
                                    <input id="TxtBuscar" class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="50" />
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="table-responsive">

                            <asp:GridView ID="GvwProducto" runat="server" Required="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table" Width="100%"
                                BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" GridLines="Horizontal"
                                DataKeyNames="Id">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="ID" Visible="false"></asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Codigo" HeaderText="CÓDIGO">
                                        <ItemStyle Width="80px" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Nombre" HeaderText="NOMBRE"></asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Marca" HeaderText="MARCA"></asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Modelo" HeaderText="MODELO"></asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Linea" HeaderText="LINEA"></asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Tipo" HeaderText="TIPO"></asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Existencia" HeaderText="EXIST."></asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                            AJUSTE
                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="TxtAjuste" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemStyle Width="80px" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#7b777a" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" />
                                <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="warning" />
                            </asp:GridView>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="AutorizacionFrm" style="display:none;">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">

                    <div role="form">

                       <h3 class="text-center" style="color:#fff">Se requiere autorización</h3>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Correo electrónico:</label>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtEmail" CssClass="form-control" ForeColor="White" MaxLength="100" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Contraseña:</label>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtPassword" CssClass="form-control" ForeColor="White" TextMode="Password" MaxLength="15" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <br />

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group text-right">
                                    <a href="#" id="LnkCancelarAutorizacion" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Cancelar</a>
                                    <asp:Button ID="BtnAutorizar" CssClass="btn btn-border-theme btn-lg" runat="server" Text="Autorizar" OnClick="BtnAutorizar_Click" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="../../Contenido/js/jquery.validate-1.15.0.js"></script>
<script src="../../Contenido/js/jquery.uitablefilter.js"></script>

  <%--Busqueda rapida--%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#TxtBuscar").keyup(function () {
            Grilla = $("#<%=GvwProducto.ClientID%>");
            $.uiTableFilter(Grilla, this.value);
        });
    });
</script>
<%-- Control de la ventana modal de autorizacion --%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#LnkSolictarAutorizacion').click(function () {
            MostrarVentanaAutorizacion();
            $('#<%=TxtEmail.ClientID%>').focus();
        });

        $('#LnkCancelarAutorizacion').click(function () {
            $.unblockUI();
        });

        $('#<%=BtnAutorizar.ClientID%>').click(function () {
            $.unblockUI();
            __doPostBack('BtnAutorizar', '');
        });

    });
</script>
```

Del lado del servidor tengo lo siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using ClosedXML.Excel;
using Oranxe.Datos.Conexion;
using Oranxe.Datos.Modelos;
using Oranxe.Solucion.layout;

namespace Oranxe.Solucion.admin
{
    public partial class AlmacenFrm : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                GvwProducto.DataSource = ConsultarListaProductos();
                GvwProducto.DataBind();
            }
        }
    protected void LnkDescargarInventario_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "Inventario_Almacen_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy") + ".xlsx");
        XLWorkbook XlLibro = new XLWorkbook();
        XlLibro.Worksheets.Add(ConsultarListaProductos(), "Inventario almacén");
        MemoryStream XlMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        XlLibro.SaveAs(XlMemoryStream);
        XlMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }

    protected void BtnAutorizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MostrarMensaje(EnumMdl.Mensaje.Correcto, "Procesado correctamente.");
    }

    #region METODOS

    DataTable ConsultarListaProductos()
    {
        DataTable ListaProductos = new DataTable();

        OranxeDB conn = new OranxeDB();

        conn.InitCommand("ConsultarAlmacenInventario");
        conn.Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpresaId", EmpresaId);

        conn.DataAdapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(conn.Command);
        conn.DataAdapter.Fill(ListaProductos);

        return ListaProductos;
    }

    string UsuarioId
    {
        get
        {
            AdminMstr mstr = (AdminMstr)Master;
            return mstr.Usuarioid;
        }
    }

    string Perfilid
    {
        get
        {
            AdminMstr mstr = (AdminMstr)Master;
            return mstr.PerfilId;
        }
    }

    string EmpresaId
    {
        get
        {
            AdminMstr mstr = (AdminMstr)Master;
            return mstr.EmpresaId;
        }
    }

    void MostrarMensaje(EnumMdl.Mensaje Tipo, string Mensaje)
    {
        AdminMstr mstr = (AdminMstr)Master;
        mstr.MostrarMensaje(Tipo, Mensaje);
    }


    #endregion


}
```

}

Comment: ¿y eso es todo? ¿donde está tu etiqueta `form`?

Comment: Hola, Estoy utilizando MASTER PAGE, un detalle que pase por alto, la etiqueta del FORM de manera generalizada se encuentra ahí, en la pagina maestra. ¿Requieres ver también el código HTML desde la Master Page?

Comment: pues estaría bien echar un vistazo a ese form, además falta el encabezado de la página, hay que revisar que el code behind y la clase de la que hereda es correcta, me refiero a algo asi como `<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Application.WebForm2" %>`

Comment: Pues mira, el encabezado de la pagina esta asi:  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Solucion/layout/AdminMstr.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AlmacenFrm.aspx.cs" Inherits="Oranxe.Solucion.admin.AlmacenFrm" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

Comment: y el code behind? hay que editar y meter todo eso en la pregunta a fin de ver si esta haciendo el binding desde el aspx hasta el code behind

Comment: te contesto una de las preguntas que haces, para dar submit del formulario por código usando Javascript haces `$("#myform").submit();` donde #myform es el `id` de la etiqueta form, que luce asi en tu aspx `<form id="myform" runat="server">`

Comment: sin embargo el botón que has puesto debería funcionar, pero para revisar eso necesito ver el código que no estás publicando, así que dejamos por acá

Comment: Hola, estaba haciendo algunas pruebas añadiendo al boton BtnAutorizar la propiedad OnClienteClick y  Listeners de Jquery para ejecutar el .submit() del formulario como lo sugeriste,  en efecto hace el postback, pero no llama al evento BtnAutorizar_Click,  solo al Page_load, en un momento actualizo la información y publico el código restante, agradezco mucho el seguimiento que estas dando.

Comment: puede que por algún motivo el código del designer `AlmacenFrm.aspx.designer.cs` no se haya actualizado para agregar el evento click. A veces me ha pasado eso. Lo que hice para arreglarlo fue volver a meter el botón.

Comment: Hagamos una cosa, vas a `AlmacenFrm.aspx` busca el botón `BtnAutorizar`, le borras `OnClick="BtnAutorizar_Click"` y tratas de volver a escribirlo. Cuando llegas al signo de `=` te tiene que salir una lista de los metodos (si no la ves, das Ctrl+Space), elige el metodo click y das enter.  A ver si con eso te actualiza el designer y enlaza el evento. De lo contrario yo borraría volvería a meter el botón, pero esta vez en vista diseño, arrastrando el botón desde Tools.

Comment: Ya lo solucione amigo, muchísimas gracias, me diste la pista al sugerirme la funcion $('#myform).submit()

Comment: esta bien, pero esto te puede volver a pasar con los webforms, ese fichero del design a veces no se actualiza bien. Es una lacra que parece estar solucionada con WPF.

Comment: Ok amigo, tendré eso en cuenta

Answer (score 0):

Ya esta solucionado, al final fue muy sencillo, simplemente reemplace el ASP:BUTTON  por un ASP:LINKBUTTON. Parece ser que BLOCKUI de JQUERY bloquea los SUBMIT provenientes de un boton normal y los LinkButton lo manejan de una forma diferente... Javascript:_DoPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument)